# Query for getting data not attached to a particular variable - JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, many-to-many

I have a table of `Employee`'s and a `Meeting` variable (also I have a table for Meeting). The relationship beetween `Meeting` and `Employee` is `many-to-many`. Is it possible to write a JPA Query which gets all the Employees from the database which are attached to the Meeting variable. If so what is the query ? The other option is to get all Employees and see which ones are not in the Meeting variable, but maybe is slow. Any ideas what should I do ?

Comment: @FranMontero Employee has a List<Meeting>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example this is your Employee entity:

```
@Entity
public class Employee  {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Meeting> meetings;
    ...
}
```

> Query: Get all the Employees from the database which are attached to
>   the Meeting variable

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE :meeting MEMBER OF e.meetings
```

> Query: Get all Employees and see which ones are not in the Meeting
>   variable

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE :meeting NOT MEMBER OF e.meetings
```

Sample code:

```
String query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE :meeting MEMBER OF e.meetings";

Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
meeting.setId(1);

TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery(query, Employee.class);
List<Employee> employeesInMeeting = query.setParameter("meeting", meeting).getResultList();  
// this will select all employees that has a meeting with id=1 in their list
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a little different. The relationship is `many-to-many`.

Comment: It will also work with Many-to-Many. I updated the code to reflect that. The code will work as long as it is a collection relationship.